# Save to a path with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with a lot of rows with a hash and some text in the format

```
DEADBEEF Some text
CAFEBABE More text
DEADBEEF Blah, blah
```

I want to split this, line by line, into files named by the hash. I managed to do that with awk:

```
awk '{ print substr($0, 10, 1000) >> substr($0, 1, 8); close(substr($0, 1, 8))}'
```

That gives me a file named DEADBEEF with the content

```
Some text
Blah, blah
```

and another file CAFEBABE with the content

```
More text
```

The problem is, I have a lot of files and the file system gets slow with lots of files in one folder, so I want to split the files in some folders, like DE/DEADBEEF and CA/CAFEBABE.

How can I do that? *Can* I do it?

Comment: You may `sort` your input file, and create an index with pointers to wherever place starts a section that should represent a specific file. While writing the index, you may as well rewrite the sorted input, removing the hash data. In case you need the ordering between lines in of the same section to be the same from the initial file, just use a stable sort algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
awk '{ 
    d=substr($0, 1, 2);                           # Determine output dir. name
    f=d "/" substr($0, 1, 8);                     # Determine output file path.
    if (!dirs[d]++) system("mkdir -p \"" d "\""); # Make sure output dir. exists.
    print substr($0, 10, 1000) >> f;              # Output line.
    close(f);                                     # Close output file.
  }
  ' file
```

**Caveats**:

- Since the output files are blindly *appended* to (`>>`), you should make sure that the output folders are empty before running the command.
  (It is fine if the output folders themselves pre-exist.)
- The `(!dirs[d]++)` condition ensure that `system()` is only called for directories that haven't been created yet (by using an associative array named `dirs` created on demand) - as OP @geon has determined through benchmarking, this optimization greatly increases performance.

Comment: As a less intrusive fix, you could just `cut -c1-2 inputfile | sort -u | xargs mkdir -p` before running an only slightly more elaborate version of your original Awk script. I'm thinking removing the `system` call from the Awk script would make it faster, but I haven't performed any measurements.

Comment: I believe you can use just `substr($0,10)` and lose the artificial 1000 limit.

Comment: @tripleee: Good point, but I retained the `substr()`call from the OP, since I did not know whether it was intentional or not.

Comment: @tripleee: Re pre-processing with `cut ...`: interesting idea; if you get around to comparing the performance, do let us know. I've just included an optimization where `system()` is only called for directory names not yet encountered - that should help.

Comment: @mklement0: I benchmarked your code with and without the optimization. For the unoptimized code, it was pretty slow. I didn't let it complete, but I timed one folder to 00:01:03. The projection for all 256 folders is 04:28:48. With the optimization, it completed in 00:06:30 - a factor of 41. Nice!

Comment: @mklement0: I included the optimization in the code, since it was so essential for performance.

Comment: @geon: Great; thanks for letting me know; looks like your edit was rejected (by others); I'll redo it myself.

Answer (score 3):

with pure shell

```
while read -r filename content
do
  dir=${filename:0:2}
  mkdir -p "${dir}"
  echo "$content" >> "${dir}/${filename}"
done < file
```

Comment: +1, but perhaps (a) rename the _variable_ `file` to `filename` so as to distinguish it from the input filename _literal_ of the same name, and (b) I suggest double-quoting `${d}` and `${d}/${file}`, to be safe.